# specify shell for ssh session

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, scp

I am logging to a remote server via ssh as user `www-data`. User `www-data` on the server has his default shell set to `/bin/sh`, and when I log in, I get dash as my shell. I can then type `bash` and get `bash` shell.

I would like to log in into bash directly, when I ssh in. But I don't want to change the default shell on the server. I want my change only to affect ssh session.

I have tried putting `command="/bin/bash"` infront of my public key in `.ssh/authorized_keys`, but this has another side effect: while bash works as default shell when logging in, `scp` stopped working. I can no longer scp files to or from the remore server.

**How can I set `bash` as default shell for ssh session, without breaking other applications ?**

Comment: `ssh user@host.example.com /bin/bash` didn't work?

Comment: @DopeGhoti:  I'm also curious about it but I suspect it'll have the same issue as with his `command=..` syntax.

Comment: I doubt it, as specifying it on the `ssh` commandline should not have any effect upon `scp`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a similar issue on one system I use (default shell is `bash`, I want `ksh93`, and `chsh` doesn't work).

My solution, adapted for your situation, is to `exec` the desired shell from `~/.profile`, which Dash reads on startup. Bash doesn't touch `~/.profile` unless it doesn't find `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` (in that order, see the Bash manual).

```
# in ~/.profile:
if [ "$SHELL" != "/usr/bin/bash" -a -n "$SSH_TTY" -a -x /usr/bin/bash ]; then
    export SHELL="/usr/bin/bash"
    exec $SHELL -l
fi
```

SSH sets `SSH_TTY` in interactive SSH sessions, so we're checking to see whether that's set (non-empty string) before making sure Bash is available and executing it. I'm setting and exporting `SHELL` in case any other application looks at it, and to avoid Bash running into an infinite loop due to missing both `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bash_login` and thus trying to execute `~/.profile` again.

Comment: thanks. With one important modification, your suggested approach works. Executing `$SHELL -l` caused a fork bomb. Apparently, `bash -l` reads `.profile` as well. When omitting `-l`, everything works as expected.

Comment: Probably because you lack both `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bash_login`?

Comment: See my edit to my answer, which makes the `if` statement fail if we're already running Bash. (not sure this is really required since it should pick up the other init files instead).